# How can I take "hot" database backups for mysql without affecting application transactions?

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I am running an application with mysql as the database and is hosted on private servers. Since, it contains very sensitive data, I am not allowed to use any of the cloud services or third party plugins which have slightest access to data. This is a legal mandate and I cant go round it. So, options like AWS, MySQL Enterprise backup or any such service is out of question. To add to it, I **cant have replicas** around the database because of some legal issues.

I want to take production backups at hourly frequency. The size of data as of now is 20gb + and is expected to grow at a rate of 7-8 gbs per month. All the tables are using `innodb` engine.

So, I cant simply run `mysqldump` for taking a sql dump. I can not have downtime on my application. One approach would be to copy the entire data folder and keep it zipped.

What would be the most suitable approach to take hot database backups without affecting application transactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Percona's xtrabackup](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/LATEST/index.html) is widely used among database administrators. Be sure to read the manual carefully.

Comment: Also note, that I'm only answering, because following answers like farbiondriven's would be "dangerous". Questions looking for third party apps or other ressources are not on-topic on this site, though.

Comment: Didnt it stop supporting innodb engine?

Comment: Where do you have that from? The whole tool is written just for InnoDB and XtraDB. And it says so in the tool description. Sounds like complete nonsense to me.

Comment: I came across this sentence on the link you had shared. "Support for InnoDB 5.1 builtin has been removed in Percona XtraBackup 2.1".

Comment: This means that it doesn't support an older version of InnoDB anymore. Not that it doesn't support InnoDB at all.

Comment: May the downvoter care to explain what the downvote is for?

Comment: @KetanPatil So, is this a solution for you?

Comment: still trying it out.